# How to draw a background for an endless scrolling RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-recyclerview, background

I'm developing a endless scrollable list for an android app, using the `RecyclerView` viewgroup and an `OnScrollListener` where i add the items after the user scrolled to the last item of the `RecyclerView`.

Now a want to add a black line in the middle behind the items as kind of a recycler view.

[image]

As you see, the items can have different heights.

Whats the best (and most performant) way to archieve this?

Comment: see `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

Comment: Why don't you just keep an image as a background which will have the line and the `RecyclerView` will be drawn over it?

Comment: @ReazMurshed thanks for your reply. Can i make an image to "stretch" the whole recycler background?

Comment: Yes. Just use `android:background="@drawable/background_image"` in the container layout. Please check the answer below.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try tomorrow and mark the answer as checked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using a layout like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/your_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great to know that helped!